Pandas avoid element-wise NaN check for lists
I have a dataframe with columns containing both single NaNs, as well as lists which may contain NaN elements. Example:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1, 2, 3], np.nan, [7, np.nan, np.nan], [4, 5, 6]]})

I want to check whether the cell values are single NaNs. The expected result of [False, True, False, False] is printed by the following command:
df.isna()

Now I want to check whether a particular cell, say the third element (index 2) is NaN. Run the following code:
elem = df.loc[2,'A']
pd.isna(elem)

The output is array([ False,  True,  True]) rather than False. I understand that pd.isna() and np.isnan() go element-wise over lists or arrays (and that this is a sensible default), but is there a simple command to compare the list as a whole against a single NaN instead?

So, use math.isnan or even the old school x != x to check for NaN

math.isnan wouldn't work with a list (try: math.isnan([1, 2]) -> TypeError: must be real number, not list).

@mozway ah yeah, well, x != x would work.

One simple option, especially if you plan to test multiple cells, would be to precompute a mask:
mask = df.isna()

mask.loc[2, 'A']
# False

If you really need to check a single value, ensure this is a float:
x = df.loc[2, 'A']

isinstance(x, float) and pd.isna(x)
# False

Or, force pd.isna to treat the input as a vector and aggregate with all:
pd.isna([df.loc[2, 'A']]).all()


Thanks. So when checking the whole dataframe, pre-compute, when checking individual elements, catch via isinstance(x, float).
Feels like there should be a function argument as part of np.isnan() and pd.isna() for how to treat containers, set to element-wise by default, but editable by the user :(

@silence_of_the_lambdas well, pandas is designed around non-nested items, not to have lists/arrays/dictionaries as items. Thus it also makes sense that these function expect either an item or, if an iterable, will treat them as a vector. I'm adding another approach to the answer.

@silence_of_the_lambdas no, that doesn't make any sense, the whole point of pd.isnan is to work in a vectorized fashion. If you *don't * want that, use math.isnan. The fundamental problem, though, is that you have a bunch of lists in a dataframe

@juanpa.arrivillaga: Might certainly be that dataframes should in many cases contain only non-nested items, but often one may want to have such containers. I regard alternatives such as concatening elements into a string by some separator and then anyways having to split the string whenever the individual elements are needed, as significantly worse than having lists in the dataframe. And I'd like to not have one line per container element either, which also becomes not really feasible once you have lists of different lengths in different columns.
